# Paging using angularjs bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to follow the example [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for pagination.

I have was able to get to a stage where I am able to show the new page number, but I am not able to fire a click event. What can I do to trigger `data-ng-click="setPage()"` on the pager in the example below

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="PagingModule">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var PagingModule = angular.module('PagingModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);

        PagingModule.controller('PaginationCtrl', function PaginationCtrl($scope) {


            $scope.noOfPages = 7;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;

            $scope.setPage = function () {
                alert("in");//I am unable to reach this code

            };
        }
        );


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="PaginationCtrl" class="well well-small">
        <pagination data-ng-click="setPage()" boundary-links="true" num-pages="noOfPages"
            current-page="currentPage" class="pagination-small" previous-text="&lsaquo;"
            next-text="&rsaquo;" first-text="&laquo;" last-text="&raquo;"></pagination>
        {{currentPage}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `data-ng-click` attribute for the `pagination` directive of angular-ui.  Clicking on one of the page numbers sets the `$scope.currentPage` variable in your controller, or whatever you set in the attribute `current-page="currentPage"`

You could set up a `$scope.$watch` on that variable to react to changes.

Answer (score 12):

### Use `ng-change`

Angular bootstrap pagination can use the `ng-change` attribute. It represents a function which may be called when the paging is changed. Get the current page using `ng-model`:

```
<pagination ... ng-change="setPage()" ng-model="current_page"></pagination>
```

### For older versions <= 0.11

You can define a function in controller and pass it an attribute using `on-select-change`:

```
<pagination ... on-select-change="setPage(page)"></pagination>
```

See more here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/pagination/docs/readme.md

See the breaking change to the code [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/d65901cff87ab895df997a803222f94ac223e9d3).

Comment: Thought it worth mentioning that `on-select-page` was removed in a [recent revision](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/d65901cff87ab895df997a803222f94ac223e9d3). `on-select-page` is now `ng-change`.